# Indian taxation on after-tax retirement accounts such as Roth

Tags: united-states, taxes, india, roth-ira, non-resident

How does India tax US after-tax retirement accounts such as the Roth IRA for a person who is a US non-resident for tax purposes starting age 59.5?

Answer (score 0):

After you become resident Indian for tax purposes,  you have 7 years to bring back your retirement savings. There is no tax applicable. After 7 years any such funds would be taxed.

Comment: Thank you. Is there no tax credit for after-tax retirement savings? What about credit for the foreign tax paid when distributions are taken from before-tax savings? Also, what are the tax rates if the money is not brought within 7 years?

Comment: The issue is with US taxes: "bringing back retirement savings" such as IRAs or 401(k) plan assets would require a withdrawal from those plans which, in general, are US-taxable events (even for Roth IRAs) as well as penalizable events for those under 59.5 years of age. Whether that money (less US tax paid?) can be put into a retirement account in India is a separate issue.

Comment: @Dilip Sarwate So what is the best course of action?